# how to read .glsl file from shader class using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, glsl

Hello I am trying to recreate a visual studio 2022 project using cmake I am stuck at the part where I have to read the .glsl vert and frag part from the file. I cant get to read the file how can I read the .glsl files, please help can provide more info if needed.

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── README.md
├── Externallibs
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── Program
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── src
│       └── main.cpp
└── EngineLibray
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── Graphics
    │   ├── Renderer
    │   ├── Mesh
    │   ├── Shader  //Contains Shader class and .glsl for vert and frag with a cmakelist.txt
    │   ├── Window
    │   └── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── Core
    │   └── CMakeLists.txt
    └── Platfrom
        └── CMakeLists.txt
```

Shader CMakeLists.txt contains-

```
set(LIBRARY_HEADER "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/Shader.h")
set(LIBRARY_SOURCE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Shader.cpp")
add_library(Shader STATIC
    ${LIBRARY_HEADER}
    ${LIBRARY_SOURCE}
)

target_include_directories(Shader 
    PUBLIC
        include/
    PRIVATE
        src/
)

target_link_libraries(Shader PRIVATE ExternalLibs)
```

calling the function from

Renderer.cpp

```
const char* Render::VertShader()
{
    //Vertex shader 
    static const char* vShader = "vShader.glsl";

    return vShader;
}

const char* Render::FragShader()
{
    //Fragment shader
    static const char* fShader = "fShader.glsl";

    return fShader;
}

void Render::CreateShader()
{
    pShader = new Shader();
    pShader->CreateFromFile(VertShader(), FragShader());
    ShaderList.push_back(pShader);
}
```

iam getting this error -

```
Failed to read vShader.glsl! File doesn't exist.Failed to read fShader.glsl! File doesn't exist.
```

I am not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Does the working directory of the executable you are running contain the shaders? If not, you have to set the correct path for them, seems unrelated to cmake.

Comment: @Quimby I know for sure the executable directory doesn't have any shader files, should i move the shader files to program/src this contain my main.cpp and use `add_custom_target` to set it up or do i have to do something else.

Comment: This has nothing to do with cmake again. This is just how executables on all operating system work. When you launch them, they have a working directory and any relative paths to files are taken with respect to this directory. So it just depends on what path are you using and from what path are you launching the executable. AFAIK if you double-click on the .exe then the working directory is set to the directory of the .exe, then you need to move the shaders there for them to be found.

Comment: @Quimby Thanks for the reply man i tried placing the shaders to the exe location `\out\build\x64-debug\Program\EngineSource.exe` but i am getting the same error. added both in the project source and binary folders :_(

Comment: But where are you launching the `EngineSource.exe` from? That is what matters...Anyway, I would suggest creating a file by the program and see where the file ends up being created, that is the directory where the shaders must be located.

Comment: @Quimby I tired the following the I created a test.txt right next to the main.cpp and made a function to read that file from main.cpp and once I build the project it gets auto copied to the `out/build/x64-debug/Program/test.txt' this is also where the exe is but when I run the exe I get the same error as above. What am I doing wrong, what to do to correct it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253959/discussion-between-gloriousdemonfist-and-quimby).

Comment: @Quimby I tried the same step in vs code and it works but the same in vs 2022 doesn't why is this happening I am clueless.

Comment: I do not know how to explain it to you. "When I run the exe" - WHERE are you running the exe FROM? What is the working directory of the launched process? Please read on what *working directory* is and how it is set. Again, this has nothing to do with Cmake nor even C++, this is (every) OS thing. Sure it might work with VS code because those IDEs override the working directory if you launch the exe through them.

Comment: @Quimby Solved the problem man did few things I firstly CMakepreset.json was not configured at all so I copied a working one to the project directory which did nothing. Secondly I made a second project from scratch and pasted all the file and CMakePreset.json in it and it started to work idk what worked but its working now thanks you so much for guiding me I learned a lot man Thanks again.